# Multiple Condition Index/Match/Sum using conditions that are not present in all cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-columns, conditional-statements, sumifs

Below, please find a screenshot that will provide some context for my question.

[image]

The above is a modified version of output from a reporting tool used by my company.  This report is spit out in Excel 2003 format and I will be manipulating it in Excel2010.  I cannot change the format of the output.

My issues with the above are twofold.  First, as far as I can tell, the app that generates the report uses nonbreaking spaces everywhere.  So simple MATCH statements on something like "Not Blue" will oftentimes return an N/A because I'm searching using a "normal" space between "Not" and "Blue".  The other issue is that I cannot figure out how to do a SUMIFS using criteria from the first three columns (to total all Data 1 values where I have Level 1/Blue/Green as my criteria, for example).  The cells in columns 1 and 2 are coming over as merged cells and I'd have to manually unmerge them and then copy down the appropriate cell value.  This would be painful.

I am hoping there is some way to get around these limitations so that I can write SUMIF formulas (or INDEX/MATCH or SUMPRODUCT or any other summing/matching formulas) relatively easily against the format being spit out by the report, without having to majorly modify the output format.  My goal is to set up a standard calculations page which would do lookups against the report spit out by my company's application.  To simplify end-user interaction, I want to be able to have them just copy/paste the output from the application into a sheet of my processing tool, which would then figure out the various totals I need.

I am perfectly willing to explore VBA as well as formula-based solutions.

Comment: Can you do a Find/Replace to solve the first issue about the spaces? For the second issue, you can unmerge and then use Go To to fill all the resulting blank cells with the upper cell value.

Comment: I could do this but my preference is to not have the end user have to remember this.  I could write a quick VBA macro to do it but I've had users who don't activate macros (or even know what that is should they need to turn it on) and thus they end up not being able to do anything.  VBA is a last resort in my mind because of the active interaction requirement on the part of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum Data1 (`D2:D9`) based on the column of merged cells (`B2:B9`) showing "Not Blue", and replacing the non-breaking spaces with spaces, you could try this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((LOOKUP(ROW(B2:B9),ROW(B2:B9)/(B2:B9<>""),TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B9,CHAR(160)," ")))="Not Blue")*D2:D9)`

The `LOOKUP(.)` part of the formula evaluates to:

`{"Blue";"Blue";"Blue";"Not Blue";"Not Blue";"Not Blue";"No Answer";"No Answer;"No Answer"}`

Additional conditions can be added for other columns of merged cells by replicating this part of the formula and changing the references. For example, you could use this approach to find Data1+Data2+ Data3 for the conditions (Level 1,Not Blue, Red):

`=SUMPRODUCT((LOOKUP(.)="Level1")*(LOOKUP(.)="Not Blue")*(C2:C9="Red")*D2:F9)`

where `(LOOKUP(.)="Not Blue")` is contained in the first formula above

and `(LOOKUP(.)="Level1")` is the same but with `A2:A9` in place of `B2:B9`.

Comment: This looks promising but could you please explain a bit more how exactly this is working?  I have pretty much ignored the LOOKUP formula in the past because it requires that the search column be sorted and I cannot always guarantee that that will happen.  Will this work if the data are not sorted?

Comment: I've been playing around with your formula and I cannot get the LOOKUP portion to evaluate to {"Blue";"Blue";...}.  Rather, I'm getting an evaluation of {"Blue",0;0,"Not Blue";0;0;...}.  So I'm not able to properly evaluate the merged cells.

Comment: The data order doesn't matter for the lookup as it is based on row numbers, seemed ok in my tests - not sure why it's returning zeros for you. Also see here: http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/formula-challenge-021-sumif-in-merged-cells.11927/

Comment: would excel version matter?  it's coming across as Excel 2003 format as far as I can tell.  I'm manipulating it in Excel 2010, so I figured that would remove any limitations.

Comment: lori_m, I figured out the issue somehow.  I took your original formula and modified it as below in the answer section.  I apologize for taking credit for your answer - I didn't know how to enter a more detailed, formatted explanation in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

lori_m, I modified your formula as below and this seems to be working:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
--(LOOKUP(ROW($A$7:$A$43),ROW($A$7:$A$43)/($A$7:$A$43<>""),
TRIM(SUBSTITUTE($A$7:$A$43,CHAR(160)," ")))="Level 2"),D$7:D$43)
```

What I can't figure out is why I was originally only getting the top level merged cell value when I used your original formula.  I'm sure it was because I mis-transposed something.  But in any case, thank you so much for your help.